# Was there a backup plan in case the Shuttle toilet malfunctioned?

Tags: space-shuttle, failure, waste

**What was the plan in case the Space Shuttle toilet malfunctioned?**  How were the astronauts expected to then handle their waste?  Did they carry Apollo-style [fecal collection assemblies](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36205/26446) (poop bags)?  Or did they just have extra [fecal containment systems](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32302/26446) (diapers)?

Comment: I can't wait for this one!

Comment: @GdD That's what the astronaut said when the toilet malfunctioned!

Comment: Did you really mean ***back up*** plan? By then it would probably be too late...

Comment: According to Scott Manley, they did indeed carry Apollo-style poop bags. But those were so distasteful that a mission could be scrubbed if that was all they had to rely on.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5y0mTqK54k

Comment: Possibly not relevant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCpnwJQhoYY

Comment: I have a silly question – why could feces *not* be jettisoned in space?

Comment: @Diti: Go ahead and post that as a *new question*.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

First let's review the nominal operation of the Shuttle Waste Collection System (WCS).

[image]

(from [Shuttle Crew Operations Manual](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/390651main_shuttle_crew_operations_manual.pdf) (SCOM) page 2.25-2)

It was divided into two major systems, one for urine and one for feces.

- The urinal consisted of a hose with a crewperson's personal funnel
  attached at the business end and fan/separator units at the other.
  The fan  automatically came on when the crewperson removed the hose
  end from its cradle. The urine passed down the hose driven by air
  flow from the fan, then was separated from the air by the separator
  part of the fan/separator, and stored in the waste tank. This tank
  was basically identical to the potable water storage tanks. It was
  pressurized using a bellows by nitrogen from the Pressure Control
  System. Water condensed from the cabin air by the humidity control
  system was also stored in this tank. When the waste tank got full enough, it was dumped overboard.
- The commode consisted of a seat with a chamber below it for storing
  the waste. When not in use, the chamber was connected to the vacuum
  vent system and held at vacuum in order to dry out the waste. The
  commode was used by operating a handle which controlled a manual
  linkage that closed off the vacuum system, repressurized the chamber,
  and opened the aperture at the top below the crewperson. When the
  commode control handle was placed in the forward position for use,
  the fan/separator came on to provide air flow to guide the waste into
  the chamber.  After usage, returning the handle to the back position
  returned the system to the drying out configuration. Every so often
  "compactor ops" had to be done to allow adequate space in the chamber
  for continued usage.

The procedures for WCS use are found on the WCS cue card in the [Orbit Ops Checklist](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/492873main_ORB_OPS_G_M_10.pdf), reproduced below.

[image]

[image]

Off nominal operations:

As shown on the cue card,

> For a non-operational WCS, contingency waste collection devices are
> available. Fecal collection is accomplished by using an Apollo fecal
> bag. Apollo fecal bags can be stowed inside the WCS commode or in the
> wet trash (volume F) compartment. For men, the urine collection device
> (UCD) is used for urine collection. A UCD consists of a collection
> bag, a restraint assembly, and a roll-on cuff. For women, urine
> collection is accomplished via Absorbent Pants (Pull-Ups). The
> Pull-ups are a modified version of adult diapers.

(SCOM p. 2.25-6)

Some non-catastrophic failures of the WCS could be worked around.

- The vacuum vent system was critical to proper operation. If the
  vaccum vent system clogged up, this could be managed by
  cross-connecting the commode's vacuum vent system to the waste water
  overboard dump line, and opening the dump valve when the commode was
  in use.
- If the waste water overboard dump system failed, the waste water
  could be dumped through the potable water overboard dump system using a
  contingency interconnect hose.  If that too failed, it could be
  collected in flexible Contingency Water Container bags and returned
  to the ground.
- Mechanical failures of the commode control handle or linkage could be
  worked around using procedures in the In-flight Maintenance
  Checklist.
- Finally, if both fan/separators were failed, urinal operations could
  be recovered by connecting the urinal hose  directly to the waste
  water overboard dump system. However, this resulted in a direct
  connection from the crewmember to vacuum, and the procedure contained
  this immortal warning.

[image]

(From In Flight Maintenance Checklist section W, not currently online)

Comment: NASA seem to like sneaking dry jokes into their technical documentation, and the euphemistic use of the term "hard dock" is perhaps my new favourite example.

Comment: Did the astro-can ever fail on a mission?

Comment: @GdD early on there were lots of problems. The original version included a "slinger" - yes, the feces was supposed to hit the fan - and that liked to fail. A search through the Shuttle Missions Summary for 'wcs' turns up many examples. https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/outreach/SignificantIncidents/assets/space-shuttle-missions-summary.pdf  Feel free to ask a followup for details.

Comment: A follow-up? You mean a number 2 @OrganicMarble ?

Comment: We have a badge for know your sh**?

Comment: Urinal connected to vacuum? That would be a serious bl... nevermind... too easy, too easy.

Comment: Do not flush while in spacedock...

Comment: @T.J.L. Hence the warning.

Comment: Next on English.SE: when feces *not* hitting the fan is the cause of your problem, does the expression "when shit hits the fan" still apply?

Comment: "Cabin air return" on the first diagram is possibly the only label which has ever made me physically shudder on a diagram on Space SE...

Comment: @Moo you might enjoy this factoid then: The outlets for all the breathing gases introduced into the shuttle cabin were located *in the toilet compartment*

Comment: @OrganicMarble you could have waited until i had finished eating my pizza...

Comment: *This* is why regular space tourism is still a long way off.  Training your average Joe and Jane Hawaiian-shirt wearing sightseers how to properly use the space-commodes is probably unlikely to work at scale any time soon.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman maybe the Crew Dragon has a cool rechargeable electric toilet with bidet. When and if they release info about it, we can find out.

Comment: I wonder if creating a rotating cabin was an option. You get in, another person spin it up and you let the centrifugal force do the work of collecting waste in natural-ish way. But it would be too big i presume, especially when thinking of making it for 2 people for better balancing :)

Comment: @PetrÚjezdský the space toilet in 2001 (the book, not the movie) worked pretty much the way you suggest.

Comment: 'hard dock' is a perfect description: short, easy to understand, precise, not insulting. I don't think there is a better one.