# Will the Artemis lunar landers provide some privacy?

Tags: the-moon, waste, artemis-program

As we learned in [Did astronauts on the moon poop in front of each other](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32208/198) the Apollo lunar landers provided *no* privacy. The Artemis missions will have members of *both* sexes, so privacy becomes a bit more important.

Do the current known designs for Artemis lunar landers provide some privacy?

Comment: I like this question, but it may be a while before enough is known about the designs to answer it.

Comment: I don’t believe our requirement list is public, though just as with the CCP 1130 requirements you can expect that they will be eventually.  Any answers posted here are going to be based on speculation, as those working on lander requirements won’t be posting them here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of lander designs, especially the NASA reference models, are at least somewhat based on the MMSEV / Habitable Airlock design for the crewed section. This has curtains separating crew bunks from the rest of the interior.

This is a shot from the inside of an MMSEV mockup, looking rearward towards the suit hatches. To the left and right are bunk areas.

[image: MMSEV Mockup Interior]

Pic reference: I took this picture last year

Comment: Given the context of the question, you should probably mention that MMSEV includes a toilet. Reference links would also be appreciated.